# Saving an image using js

Tags: javascript

I am stuck at a point where I am getting an image from the server as a binary data and i need to save this image on my PC without any user interference.

Comment: How about posting some code ? And giving details about the exact problem you are facing ?

Answer (score 2):

Think about it for a moment. If JavaScript could save files to your PC without your explicit consent, every hacker in the world would have access to your PC in a fraction of a second. Flash has enough security problems, JavaScript doesn't need them.

In other words, what you're asking for is impossible **for good reason**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the HTML5 File API is something for you. But without user action it would be a huge security hole!

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side

http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/#the-filesaver-interface

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to save something *without* user consent? That's never a good idea.

Anyways, JavaScript isn't able to mess with your computer's filesystem, thus it can't save the image to your hard drive. You could use JavaScript to create an image on your web page, using img or canvas, and then ask the user to save it, but exactly what you want is not possible with JavaScript.

On your server page, you could create the binary data, and set certain headers to treat the page as downloadable content, and that's about as close as you can get. It'd still ask for user consent, though.